# r - ggplot2 - Add differences to grouped bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, difference

I am plotting the following data on ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

DF <- structure(list(Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Observed", "Simulated"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("EM to V6", 
    "V6 to R0", "R0 to R4", "R4 to R9"), class = "factor"), value = c(28, 
    30, 29, 35, 32, 34, 26, 29)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("Type", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(DF, aes(variable, value)) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge", stat="identity", width=.5) +
      geom_text(aes(label=value, group=Type), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.5) +
      theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
      ylab('Duration (days)') + xlab('Growth stages')
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is any graphical way to add the differences between each group of bars to the chart?

This is the data frame with the differences to be added:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(variable=c("EM to V6", "V6 to R0", "R0 to R4", "R4 to R9"), value=c(2,6,2,3)
```

The final chart would look somewhat like this (notice the coloured bars):

[image]

source: https://www.excelcampus.com/charts/variance-clustered-column-bar-chart/

Is that possible to do using ggplot?

Comment: just add a layer of bars (two each at max height per group) behind those with a slightly smaller width in a different color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `rawr` suggested, you can add a layer of bars behind the current ones with a slightly smaller width:

```
library(tidyverse)
diff_df = DF %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    spread(Type, value) %>%
    mutate(diff = Simulated - Observed)

ggplot(DF, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = Simulated), data = diff_df, stat = "identity", fill = "grey80", width = 0.4) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge", stat="identity", width=.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=value, group=Type), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label = diff, y = Simulated), vjust=-0.5, data = diff_df, hjust = 2, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
    ylab('Duration (days)') + xlab('Growth stages')
```

---

Updated code to deal with Observed sometimes being higher than Simulated:

```
library(tidyverse)
diff_df = DF %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    spread(Type, value) %>%
    mutate(diff = Simulated - Observed,
           max_y = max(Simulated, Observed),
           sim_higher = Simulated > Observed)

ggplot(DF, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = max_y), data = diff_df, stat = "identity", fill = "grey80", width = 0.4) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge", stat="identity", width=.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=value, group=Type), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label = diff, y = max_y), vjust=-0.5, data = diff_df %>% filter(sim_higher), 
              hjust = 2, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
    geom_text(aes(label = diff, y = max_y), vjust=-0.5, data = diff_df %>% filter(!sim_higher), 
              hjust = -1, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
    ylab('Duration (days)') + xlab('Growth stages')
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! But what it I have a scenario where the simulated is lower than observed? We can reproduce this by changing the original dataset: `DF[7,3] <- 29; DF[8,3] <- 26` and running your code again!

Comment: Right, it requires a bit of extra work but I was able to achieve it relatively easily. It's mostly just calculating the max of the two variables and using that as the y value, but then the labels required some extra tweaking.

Comment: Wow, that is not a code. That is a *masterpiece*! Thank you so much for the extra effort to help answer this question. Please take a look at the final image using my actual data: http://imgur.com/APg0xrv